# How to install Sitecore using SIF and Solr cloud

Tags: solr, installation

We are in process of installing Sitecore using Solrcloud using SIF. In SIF we have to pass Solr URL, Solr Root and service name in order to create collection/cores. We are not sure how to pass solr root and windows service as these details are not known in SolrCloud.

So my questions is if we need to install Sitecore using SIF with Solrcloud, how to pass the above 2 parameters.

Or is there any alternate way to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you installing Sitecore on your local?

Comment: You can refer this:  https://buoctrenmay.com/2017/10/30/a-step-by-step-guide-for-sitecore-9-installation-on-your-machine/ to install sitecore step by step.

Comment: @SunilKumar I need to install sitecore with solrcloud, not solr.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore will be installed normally but you will need to do additional work to configure Sitecore to use SolrCloud like upload the Solr configuration to Zookeeper. Add token solrCloud=true with the value of solr search key in ConnectionStrings.config file.

You can find more detail here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--setting-up-solrcloud.html

Answer (score 1):

We setup SOLR cloud in first place with all necessary cores.
As a 2nd step we installed Sitecore with local instance of SOLR.
Once Sitecore is setup we changed the necessary configurations files to point it to SOLR cloud. Although it is mentioned that SSL has to be enabled for SOLR, our SOLR cloud (without SSL) worked fine with Sitecore.

Comment: You'll have a lot of issues with xconnect unless you have modified all the configs to allow non https for solr.

Answer (score 1):

The approach that we followed is -

**Step 1** - Instead of using XP1-SingleDeveloper.ps1 file for installation, we used individual json files (that you get with XP1 Sitecore intallation package) to install instances of identityserver, cm, cd and xconnect instances.

**Step 2** - In the json files, we removed the code to create and update solr cores.

**Step 3** - After the instances were setup, we created cores on SolrCloud and provided reference of solrcloud in ConnectionStrings.config file.

**Step 4** - Then we populated and rebuild the cores and it worked fine.

**Note -** 
This approach should be followed when you have appropriate amount of time to setup CM and CD instances.